# Unable to build libcamera-apps

Tags: picamera, libcamera

im not able to build libcamera-apps on my system.

Hardware: Pi 4 B

OS: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

I fowllowed all the steps in this Docu: https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/camera_software.html#building-libcamera-apps

Thats the steps I have done so far:

1. sudo apt install libcamera-dev libepoxy-dev libjpeg-dev libtiff5-dev
2. sudo apt install -y qtbase5-dev libqt5core5a libqt5gui5 libqt5widgets5
3. sudo apt install libavcodec-dev libavdevice-dev libavformat-dev libswresample-dev
4. sudo apt install -y cmake libboost-program-options-dev libdrm-dev libexif-dev
5. sudo pip3 install ninja meson
6. git clone https://github.com/raspberrypi/libcamera-apps.git
7. cd libcamera-apps
8. meson setup build -Denable_libav=true -Denable_drm=true -Denable_egl=true -Denable_qt=true -Denable_opencv=false -Denable_tflite=false
9. meson compile -C build

This is the Error in the terminal:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/wa/sdk/libcamera-apps $ meson compile -C build
INFO: autodetecting backend as ninja
INFO: calculating backend command to run: /usr/local/bin/ninja -C /home/pi/wa/sdk/libcamera-apps/build
ninja: Entering directory `/home/pi/wa/sdk/libcamera-apps/build'
[4/34] Compiling C++ object libcamera_app.so.1.2.2.p/image_dng.cpp.o
FAILED: libcamera_app.so.1.2.2.p/image_dng.cpp.o 
c++ -Ilibcamera_app.so.1.2.2.p -I. -I.. -Icore -I/usr/include/libcamera -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/qt5 -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -fdiagnostics-color=always -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror -std=c++17 -O3 -pedantic -Wno-unused-parameter -faligned-new -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wno-psabi -ftree-vectorize -DLIBAV_PRESENT=1 -DLIBDRM_PRESENT=1 -DLIBEGL_PRESENT=1 -DQT_PRESENT=1 -fPIC -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -pthread -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB -MD -MQ libcamera_app.so.1.2.2.p/image_dng.cpp.o -MF libcamera_app.so.1.2.2.p/image_dng.cpp.o.d -o libcamera_app.so.1.2.2.p/image_dng.cpp.o -c ../image/dng.cpp
../image/dng.cpp:73:13: error: ‘RGGB16_PISP_COMP1’ is not a member of ‘libcamera::formats’
   73 |  { formats::RGGB16_PISP_COMP1, { "RGGB-16-PISP", 16, TIFF_RGGB, false, true } },
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../image/dng.cpp:74:13: error: ‘GRBG16_PISP_COMP1’ is not a member of ‘libcamera::formats’
   74 |  { formats::GRBG16_PISP_COMP1, { "GRBG-16-PISP", 16, TIFF_GRBG, false, true } },
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../image/dng.cpp:75:13: error: ‘GBRG16_PISP_COMP1’ is not a member of ‘libcamera::formats’
   75 |  { formats::GBRG16_PISP_COMP1, { "GBRG-16-PISP", 16, TIFF_GBRG, false, true } },
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../image/dng.cpp:76:13: error: ‘BGGR16_PISP_COMP1’ is not a member of ‘libcamera::formats’
   76 |  { formats::BGGR16_PISP_COMP1, { "BGGR-16-PISP", 16, TIFF_BGGR, false, true } },
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../image/dng.cpp:77:1: error: could not convert ‘{{libcamera::formats::SRGGB10_CSI2P, {"RGGB-10", 10, TIFF_RGGB, true, false}}, {libcamera::formats::SGRBG10_CSI2P, {"GRBG-10", 10, TIFF_GRBG, true, false}}, {libcamera::formats::SBGGR10_CSI2P, {"BGGR-10", 10, TIFF_BGGR, true, false}}, {libcamera::formats::SGBRG10_CSI2P, {"GBRG-10", 10, TIFF_GBRG, true, false}}, {libcamera::formats::SRGGB10, {"RGGB-10", 10, TIFF_RGGB, false, false}}, {libcamera::formats::SGRBG10, {"GRBG-10", 10, TIFF_GRBG, false, false}}, {libcamera::formats::SBGGR10, {"BGGR-10", 10, TIFF_BGGR, false, false}}, {libcamera::formats::SGBRG10, {"GBRG-10", 10, TIFF_GBRG, false, false}}, {libcamera::formats::SRGGB12_CSI2P, {"RGGB-12", 12, TIFF_RGGB, true, false}}, {libcamera::formats::SGRBG12_CSI2P, {"GRBG-12", 12, TIFF_GRBG, true, false}}, {libcamera::formats::SBGGR12_CSI2P, {"BGGR-12", 12, TIFF_BGGR, true, false}}, {libcamera::formats::SGBRG12_CSI2P, {"GBRG-12", 12, TIFF_GBRG, true, false}}, {libcamera::formats::SRGGB12, {"RGGB-12", 12, TIFF_RGGB, false, false}}, {libcamera::formats::SGRBG12, {"GRBG-12", 12, TIFF_GRBG, false, false}}, {libcamera::formats::SBGGR12, {"BGGR-12", 12, TIFF_BGGR, false, false}}, {libcamera::formats::SGBRG12, {"GBRG-12", 12, TIFF_GBRG, false, false}}, {libcamera::formats::SRGGB16, {"RGGB-16", 16, TIFF_RGGB, false, false}}, {libcamera::formats::SGRBG16, {"GRBG-16", 16, TIFF_GRBG, false, false}}, {libcamera::formats::SBGGR16, {"BGGR-16", 16, TIFF_BGGR, false, false}}, {libcamera::formats::SGBRG16, {"GBRG-16", 16, TIFF_GBRG, false, false}}, {libcamera::formats::R10_CSI2P, {"BGGR-10", 10, TIFF_BGGR, true, false}}, {libcamera::formats::R10, {"BGGR-10", 10, TIFF_BGGR, false, false}}, {libcamera::formats::R12, {"BGGR-12", 12, TIFF_BGGR, false, false}}, {<expression error>, {"RGGB-16-PISP", 16, TIFF_RGGB, false, true}}, {<expression error>, {"GRBG-16-PISP", 16, TIFF_GRBG, false, true}}, {<expression error>, {"GBRG-16-PISP", 16, TIFF_GBRG, false, true}}, {<expression error>, {"BGGR-16-PISP", 16, TIFF_BGGR, false, true}}}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘const std::map<libcamera::PixelFormat, BayerFormat>’
   77 | };
      | ^
      | |
      | <brace-enclosed initializer list>
[5/34] Compiling C++ object libcamera_app.so.1.2.2.p/core_options.cpp.o
FAILED: libcamera_app.so.1.2.2.p/core_options.cpp.o 
c++ -Ilibcamera_app.so.1.2.2.p -I. -I.. -Icore -I/usr/include/libcamera -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/qt5 -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -fdiagnostics-color=always -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror -std=c++17 -O3 -pedantic -Wno-unused-parameter -faligned-new -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wno-psabi -ftree-vectorize -DLIBAV_PRESENT=1 -DLIBDRM_PRESENT=1 -DLIBEGL_PRESENT=1 -DQT_PRESENT=1 -fPIC -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -pthread -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB -MD -MQ libcamera_app.so.1.2.2.p/core_options.cpp.o -MF libcamera_app.so.1.2.2.p/core_options.cpp.o.d -o libcamera_app.so.1.2.2.p/core_options.cpp.o -c ../core/options.cpp
../core/options.cpp: In member function ‘virtual bool Options::Parse(int, char**)’:
../core/options.cpp:267:15: error: ‘class libcamera::CameraConfiguration’ has no member named ‘sensorConfig’
  267 |       config->sensorConfig = libcamera::SensorConfiguration();
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../core/options.cpp:267:41: error: ‘SensorConfiguration’ is not a member of ‘libcamera’; did you mean ‘StreamConfiguration’?
  267 |       config->sensorConfig = libcamera::SensorConfiguration();
      |                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                         StreamConfiguration
../core/options.cpp:268:15: error: ‘class libcamera::CameraConfiguration’ has no member named ‘sensorConfig’
  268 |       config->sensorConfig->outputSize = size;
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../core/options.cpp:269:15: error: ‘class libcamera::CameraConfiguration’ has no member named ‘sensorConfig’
  269 |       config->sensorConfig->bitDepth = sensor_mode.depth();
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
[8/34] Compiling C++ object libcamera_app.so.1.2.2.p/core_libcamera_app.cpp.o
FAILED: libcamera_app.so.1.2.2.p/core_libcamera_app.cpp.o 
c++ -Ilibcamera_app.so.1.2.2.p -I. -I.. -Icore -I/usr/include/libcamera -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/qt5 -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -fdiagnostics-color=always -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror -std=c++17 -O3 -pedantic -Wno-unused-parameter -faligned-new -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wno-psabi -ftree-vectorize -DLIBAV_PRESENT=1 -DLIBDRM_PRESENT=1 -DLIBEGL_PRESENT=1 -DQT_PRESENT=1 -fPIC -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -pthread -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB -MD -MQ libcamera_app.so.1.2.2.p/core_libcamera_app.cpp.o -MF libcamera_app.so.1.2.2.p/core_libcamera_app.cpp.o.d -o libcamera_app.so.1.2.2.p/core_libcamera_app.cpp.o -c ../core/libcamera_app.cpp
../core/libcamera_app.cpp: In member function ‘void LibcameraApp::OpenCamera()’:
../core/libcamera_app.cpp:222:13: error: ‘class libcamera::CameraConfiguration’ has no member named ‘sensorConfig’
  222 |     config->sensorConfig = libcamera::SensorConfiguration();
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../core/libcamera_app.cpp:222:39: error: ‘SensorConfiguration’ is not a member of ‘libcamera’; did you mean ‘StreamConfiguration’?
  222 |     config->sensorConfig = libcamera::SensorConfiguration();
      |                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                       StreamConfiguration
../core/libcamera_app.cpp:223:13: error: ‘class libcamera::CameraConfiguration’ has no member named ‘sensorConfig’
  223 |     config->sensorConfig->outputSize = size;
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../core/libcamera_app.cpp:224:13: error: ‘class libcamera::CameraConfiguration’ has no member named ‘sensorConfig’
  224 |     config->sensorConfig->bitDepth = sensorMode.depth();
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../core/libcamera_app.cpp: In member function ‘void LibcameraApp::ConfigureViewfinder()’:
../core/libcamera_app.cpp:373:19: error: ‘class libcamera::CameraConfiguration’ has no member named ‘sensorConfig’
  373 |   configuration_->sensorConfig = libcamera::SensorConfiguration();
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../core/libcamera_app.cpp:373:45: error: ‘SensorConfiguration’ is not a member of ‘libcamera’; did you mean ‘StreamConfiguration’?
  373 |   configuration_->sensorConfig = libcamera::SensorConfiguration();
      |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                             StreamConfiguration
../core/libcamera_app.cpp:374:19: error: ‘class libcamera::CameraConfiguration’ has no member named ‘sensorConfig’
  374 |   configuration_->sensorConfig->outputSize = options_->viewfinder_mode.Size();
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../core/libcamera_app.cpp:375:19: error: ‘class libcamera::CameraConfiguration’ has no member named ‘sensorConfig’
  375 |   configuration_->sensorConfig->bitDepth = options_->viewfinder_mode.bit_depth;
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../core/libcamera_app.cpp: In member function ‘void LibcameraApp::ConfigureStill(unsigned int)’:
../core/libcamera_app.cpp:439:19: error: ‘class libcamera::CameraConfiguration’ has no member named ‘sensorConfig’
  439 |   configuration_->sensorConfig = libcamera::SensorConfiguration();
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../core/libcamera_app.cpp:439:45: error: ‘SensorConfiguration’ is not a member of ‘libcamera’; did you mean ‘StreamConfiguration’?
  439 |   configuration_->sensorConfig = libcamera::SensorConfiguration();
      |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                             StreamConfiguration
../core/libcamera_app.cpp:440:19: error: ‘class libcamera::CameraConfiguration’ has no member named ‘sensorConfig’
  440 |   configuration_->sensorConfig->outputSize = options_->mode.Size();
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../core/libcamera_app.cpp:441:19: error: ‘class libcamera::CameraConfiguration’ has no member named ‘sensorConfig’
  441 |   configuration_->sensorConfig->bitDepth = options_->mode.bit_depth;
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../core/libcamera_app.cpp: In member function ‘void LibcameraApp::ConfigureVideo(unsigned int)’:
../core/libcamera_app.cpp:499:19: error: ‘class libcamera::CameraConfiguration’ has no member named ‘sensorConfig’
  499 |   configuration_->sensorConfig = libcamera::SensorConfiguration();
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../core/libcamera_app.cpp:499:45: error: ‘SensorConfiguration’ is not a member of ‘libcamera’; did you mean ‘StreamConfiguration’?
  499 |   configuration_->sensorConfig = libcamera::SensorConfiguration();
      |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                             StreamConfiguration
../core/libcamera_app.cpp:500:19: error: ‘class libcamera::CameraConfiguration’ has no member named ‘sensorConfig’
  500 |   configuration_->sensorConfig->outputSize = options_->mode.Size();
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../core/libcamera_app.cpp:501:19: error: ‘class libcamera::CameraConfiguration’ has no member named ‘sensorConfig’
  501 |   configuration_->sensorConfig->bitDepth = options_->mode.bit_depth;
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../core/libcamera_app.cpp: In member function ‘void LibcameraApp::StartCamera()’:
../core/libcamera_app.cpp:675:59: error: ‘AeFlickerMode’ is not a member of ‘controls’
  675 |  if (options_->flicker_period && !controls_.get(controls::AeFlickerMode) &&
      |                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
../core/libcamera_app.cpp:676:39: error: ‘AeFlickerMode’ is not a member of ‘controls’
  676 |   camera_->controls().find(&controls::AeFlickerMode) != camera_->controls().end() &&
      |                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
../core/libcamera_app.cpp:677:39: error: ‘AeFlickerPeriod’ is not a member of ‘controls’
  677 |   camera_->controls().find(&controls::AeFlickerPeriod) != camera_->controls().end())
      |                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../core/libcamera_app.cpp:679:27: error: ‘AeFlickerMode’ is not a member of ‘controls’
  679 |   controls_.set(controls::AeFlickerMode, controls::FlickerManual);
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
../core/libcamera_app.cpp:679:52: error: ‘FlickerManual’ is not a member of ‘controls’
  679 |   controls_.set(controls::AeFlickerMode, controls::FlickerManual);
      |                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
../core/libcamera_app.cpp:680:27: error: ‘AeFlickerPeriod’ is not a member of ‘controls’
  680 |   controls_.set(controls::AeFlickerPeriod, options_->flicker_period.get<std::chrono::microseconds>());
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[9/34] Compiling C++ object libcamera_app.so.1.2.2.p/output_file_output.cpp.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Thanks for the support.

Best regards
Florian

Answer (score 0):

I used a Ubuntu 22.04 docker image, so my development environment is a little different, but I got the same error.
I was able to install by using tag v1.2.2.

```
git clone https://github.com/raspberrypi/libcamera-apps.git -b v1.2.2
```

Subsequent steps are the same. I hope this helps you.

Hardware: Raspberry Pi 4B 
OS: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Docker image: Ubuntu:22.04

Comment: Hello @hwajeon
if im using this i running in a different error. 
../core/libcamera_app.cpp:624:39: error: ‘AeFlickerMode’ is not a member of ‘controls’
  624 |   camera_->controls().find(&controls::AeFlickerMode) != camera_->controls().end() &&

Comment: Hello. Is libcamera up to date? I found the following forum page.
https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=354529
I am referring to https://libcamera.org/getting-started.html and have the latest libcamera installed.

Comment: Hello,
thank u for your reply! I tried the getting started Link which u sent me:  libcamera.org/getting-started.html
With the linked git repo i was able to build and install libcamera.
git clone https://git.libcamera.org/libcamera/libcamera.git
As I understand it the libary "libcamera-apps" is outdatetd but still linked in the official doku?

Comment: Hi all, just tried to build libcamera-app and had the same errors.  Switched to v1.2.2 which fixed the SensorConfiguration problem but I still have the AeFlickerMode error.  libcamera is probably fine in my experience, libcamera-app is more likely suffering from a lack of systematic updates. All I want to do is to get low resolution stills off the camera (in C) and no doubt it can be done using libcamera but the "API" is not an api and I have not found any examples of something so simple. Using libcamera-app at least had examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use libcamera from https://github.com/raspberrypi/libcamera.  It has raspberry pi specific code.